# La opción de modificar stored procedures aparece gris (mssql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql, microsoft, ssms

Use el usuario sa, le agregue a su usuario normal sys admin, luego le di todos los grant y "with grant" disponibles y siempre aparece en gris (no disponible).

Me enviaron la base de datos y la instale. Pero supuse que el usuario sa debería poder acceder a modificar los procedimientos almacenados.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema era que no podía entrar a ver el código de los procedimientos almacenados de la base de datos, la opción de modificar que es la que me permite ver el código después de creado un procedimiento almacenado cuando le das clic derecho sobre el procedimiento aparecía en gris, ósea, que estaba deshabilitado.

Me di cuenta luego que el problema era que cuando se guardaron los procedimientos almacenados lo hicieron con el comando Encrypt, osea que están encryptados.